# Convert an C++ STDCALL in C#

Tags: c#, c++

How to convert this code to C# ?

```
static void STDCALL HandleVideoStatic(PVOID pContext, BYTE * apData[3], VideoSampleInfo_T * pVSI)
{
    ((TMediaCallbackHandler *)pContext)->HandleVideo(apData, pVSI);
}

WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(m_ahChannels[i], &m_aMediaHandler[i], HandleVideoStatic);
```

the STDCALL is a weird method with me.

Comment: have you tried dllimport ?

Comment: I tried, but I don't how to write it to C#

Comment: That should be easy enough to do with p/invoke, but in order to do it one would need to know what `VideoSampleInfo_T` was, and the semantics of the `apData` parameter. That's information that only you have.

Comment: So sad, I have only the SDK, no document

Answer (score 0):

use PInvoke. in C# it is short for Platform invoke which make you able to call native API from .net managed environment. see this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx